# IN statement transition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using a subquery list all male employees with salaries higher than any female employee. Does this look right? Also I need to change it to an IN statement. Everything I've tried returns all female salaries.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Salary
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary > ALL
(Select Salary FROM Employee
WHERE Gender = 'F')
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. It looks like the query should yield "Any employee with a salary greater than any female employee." I think you ought to add a where clause in the main query to limit the output to men only.

Could you describe how the "IN" transition should work?

Comment: I basically need the same statement just using IN instead of ALL.

Comment: I don't think there is a sensible way to change this to an `IN`, though you can change it to a `NOT EXISTS`. Would that meet your needs?

Comment: @SteveLovell No unfortunately not. Any other ideas on how to pull the same data as Gordon provided using an IN statement instead?

Comment: Well, it would be easy to add an `IN` but it would be artificial and completely unnecessary. Hate to ask but why must the solution use `IN`?

Comment: @SteveLovell working on a project and thats what has been asked. I know they'll return the same result. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, for the record, I think Gordon's answer is technically much better than what follows. He's doing it right. The requirement to use `IN` is frankly bizarre.

Since `x > ALL y` is naturally translated to a `NOT EXISTS y such that x <= y`
and `EXISTS` can relatively naturally be translated to `IN`, we could do this as `x NOT IN (z such that z <= y)`. Assuming the `Employee` table has a PK field called `EmployeeID`, you can do this as follows (I threw in some bonus `IN`s for you for free):

```
SELECT 
    m.FirstName,
    m.LastName,
    m.Salary
FROM
    Employee m
WHERE
    m.Gender IN ('M')
    AND m.Salary is not null
    AND m.EmployeeID NOT IN
    (
     select m2.EmployeeID
     from Employee m2
     where m2.Salary <= (select f.Salary 
                         FROM Employee f
                         where f.Gender IN ('F'))
    )
    AND 'Why' IN ('Why','IN','Why','?')
    AND 'Why' NOT IN ('Another','Way','?')
```

This is horrid and much less efficient than Gordon's answer.

If this is part of an assignment for a course, one has to wonder what the person setting this assignment was thinking. There's the obvious possibility that they simply don't know what they are doing, but perhaps they wanted you to jump through some logical hoops or to teach you that it's often possible to achieve the same thing in multiple different ways and that these may or may not be equally efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write this as:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Employee m
WHERE m.Gender = 'M' AND
      m.Salary > (SELECT MAX(f.Salary)
                  FROM Employee f
                  WHERE f.Gender = 'F'
                 );
```

I like this version because it is quite explicit.  It is almost a direct translation of "Get all males that earn more than the highest paid female."

Your version also works, under the assumption that `gender` only takes on two values.  However, it relies on subtlety:  The comparison is `>`.  So, no *female* can have a salary higher than all females (including herself). Hence, the outer query can only return not-females, which happen to be males.

Instead of going through those mental gymnastics, the condition on `= 'M'` makes the intention of the query much clearer.

With that condition, the query is clearer:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Employee m
WHERE m.Gender = 'M' AND
      m.Salary > ALL (SELECT f.Salary
                      FROM Employee f
                      WHERE f.Gender = 'F'
                     );
```

I should note that this version is better than the version with `MAX()` in one edge case.  When there are no females, this will return all employees.  The version with `MAX()` will return no rows at all.

I should add:  It is not obvious how to turn this query into a version using `IN`, at least in a sensible way.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I really don't understand the IN statement in this case. However, I still need to figure it out.